# How to get a Task's description inside runStep()?

Tags: plugin-development, tasks

I know that I can get the default description of a Task with:

```php
$this->description;
//or
$this->getDescription();
```

But how can I get the description if it got changed on creation:

```php
craft()->tasks->createTask('Mailer', $new_description);
```

Adding it as an attribute doesn't seem "right" to me:

```php
craft()->tasks->createTask('Mailer', $new_description, array('description' => $new_description));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description you define in `getDescription()` is just the default description in the event that no description was specified when `craft()->tasks->createTask()` was called.

The *actual* description for the task is saved on the TaskModel, which you can get via `$this->model` from your Task class:

```
$description = $this->model->description;
```